# URL not getting published in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, urls

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[style=numeric,              
natbib=true,   
maxitems=1,
backend=biber]{biblatex} 

\usepackage[breaklinks=true, 
linktocpage=true,
pdftitle={My Title},
pdfsubject={},
pdfauthor={My Name},
pdfkeywords={}]{hyperref}
\bibliography{project.bib}


\begin{document}


@Misc{ansys_2009,
url = {http://orange.engr.ucdavis.edu/Documentation12.1/121/ans_ctec.pdf},
Year = {2009}}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The url link is not getting published in Bibliography. I tried writing the link in ''How published'' section as well.

Comment: Your example does not make a lot of sense. You can use the `filecontents*` environment to include the content of a .bib file in your document.
Notes are not published. Use the url field in the bibfiile. `url = {http://orange.engr.ucdavis.edu/Documentation12.1/121/ans_ctec.pdf}, `

Comment: @MaxNoe Could you please explain when you say it does not make a lot of sense. I referred different questions asked and hence I used my link in the ''Note'' and ''How published'' field.

Comment: I meant that you just copied your bib entry in your texfile. Did you try to compile your example? Certainly not.

Comment: Are you using BibTeX or `biblatex` to generate the bibliography?

Comment: @MaxNoe I compiled my example. I am able to publish two other entries which are reference to books. The URL link is the one which is not getting published.

Comment: The code you posted here is certainly not compilable . You do not even load biblatex

Comment: @MaxNoe : I have edited it accordingly.

Comment: This is still not compilable,  you cannot just add an entry of the bib file in your document

Comment: @MaxNoe As I am new to Latex, I am confused. The tex file says it's Biblatex so I am sure it's correct. But the entries into .Bib file are done using JabRef reference Manager wherein I enter the reference of Book/Url and it extracts from that automatically.

Comment: @Bruce I think i a just now even more confused than you are. Where are your troubles with the answer provided below.

Comment: @Johannes_B I will try to explain in detail. I enter all the references in a project.bib file which is accessed via Jabref reference manager. After entering the details, I load the Bibliography using \bibliography{project} and print it via \printbibliography. I entered the book references and it gets printed but when I am trying to do the same with the URL it is not generating. :( . The code which I have pasted is taken from the .bib file

Comment: @Bruce You are menitoning `bibliography` to load the database and `\printbibliography` to print the database, your example doesn't show that. Please edit the question so we know what you actually do.

Comment: @Johannes_B I have edited it as per my Tex file.

Comment: Do you have the database entry *within* your document? I don't think so, it is in a special file you are editing with Jabref. Move the url from note to urlfield. If Jabref cannot do that, use your favourite text editor to change the `bib`-file.

Comment: @Johannes_B Yes you are right. It is a special file which I am editing with Jabref. I tried the option of urlfield as well (url = {http://orange.engr.ucdavis.edu/Documentation12.1/121/ans_ctec.pdf}) . But somehow the URL in reference section is not getting published.

Comment: Please edit the question, another helper should not spend time to search the comments for useful information.

Comment: @Johannes_B Done. Could you figure out where I might be going wrong?

Comment: You cannot ping people who have not participated in the discussion in these comments. The system won't let you. The example you've given still makes no sense. The entry must be in `project.bib`, I assume. Not in your `.tex` file. In your `.tex` file, you need to *cite* the entry e.g. `\cite{ansys_2009}`.

Comment: @cfr Sorry I did not know this. As for the problem at hand, I could get the references of books in Bibliography without writing \cite{text}.

Comment: @Bruce I am just translating a little introduction to *bibliographies with LaTeX* into english. It will be ready in a few days. I hope it helps people to understand how all this works. Of course, many of such introductions have been written before.

Comment: @Bruce `\cite` is not the only citation command. It could be `\autocite` or `\citeauthor` or `\nocite` or something else. But merely having something in the `.bib` will not get it to show up in your bibliography. Period. It just doesn't work that way. The `.bib` is a database. You tell LaTeX which particular items from that database it needs to retrieve for this document. You do that, basically, using `\cite` although, as I say, there are many different citation commands any of which will cause the item to be added to your bibliography.

Answer (score 3):

## The Basics:

As you are missing some of the basics, I extended my answer a bit.

`biblatex` works like this:

- You have the information about your references in a `.bib` text file.
  This is the project.bib you seem to have created with JabRef.
- You load the package with `\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}`
- In you document, you can refer to your sources with `\cite{<key>}` where `<key>`
  is the first entry in a bib object in your project.bib.
- Add a `\printbibliography` where you want the bibliography, usually at the very end of your document.
- Now run your favourite LaTeX-Compiler (one of e.g. latex, pdflatex, xelatex, lualatex). The program will write the keys you need because you `\cite`d them to a file `mydocument.bcf`.
- Then run `biber`: `biber mydocument.bcf`, biber will look up the keys in your `project.bib` sort and format them and write them to a file with the name `mydocument.bbl`
- Now you need to run the LaTeX-Compiler at least one time more, it reads the `mydocument.bbl`-file and builds your citations and the bibliography from it.

## Adding a url to a bibentry.

For adding an URL to a source, use the `url` entry type in your bibfile.
Do not add formatting commands into the bib file, that is biblatex's job.
If it is an online only source, you should prefer `@online` to `@misc`:

```
@online{ansys_2009,
      Title = {Contact Technology Guide},
      Author = {Ansys, Inc.},
      Month = {November},
      url = {http://orange.engr.ucdavis.edu/Documentation12.1/121/ans_ctec.pdf},
      Year = {2009}
    }
```

No we can cite it like this and have the url shown in the bibliography:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{project.bib}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}        
\begin{document}
See \cite{ansys_2009}!
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

### This is the result:

[image: result]

Comment: When using biblatex, you might as well use type `online` ;-)

Comment: @Johannes_B As I am new to Latex, I am confused. The tex file says it's Biblatex so I am sure it's correct. But the entries into .Bib file are done using JabRef reference Manager wherein I enter the reference of Book/Url

Comment: I extended my answer to cover some basics

Comment: @MaxNoe : There is no field as online in my .bib file. So I am using misc

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit simplified, so please don't tell me it isn't quite this straightforward and that Biblatex can also roast your coffee beans while Biber de-fleas the dog. This is a crude overview. For details of Biber's pet-grooming features, the interested reader is respectfully referred to the manual.

To create a bibliography using the Biblatex package and Biber, you need the following:

A database containing bibliographical data for the various sources you will use in your document (and maybe for a lot of sources you won't use there, as well). Most commonly, this is a BibTeX `.bib` file.

```
% mybibliography.bib

@book{key1,
 author = ...
}
@article{key2,
 author = ...
}
@misc{key3,
 ...
}
```

Then, in the preamble of your `.tex` file, you add

```
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybibliography.bib}
```

In the body of your document, you need 2 things.

1. Commands which tell Biblatex which items it should retrieve from the database. By default, it will not retrieve any so your bibliography will be empty.
2. A command to print the bibliography.

Typically, you might have

```
Some text \cite{key1}.

Some more text \cite{key3}.

\printbibliography
```

This will add the first and third entry from the database to the document's bibliography, but not the second.

Then you run `latex` (or `pdflatex` or `xelatex` or whatever) on your file as normal. This produces a `.bcf` file with instructions for creating the bibliography for the document. This specifies which database(s) to read and which keys need to be looked up.

Then you need to run `biber` to actually retrieve the information from the database. LaTeX doesn't read the `.bib` file itself. It just tells Biber what to do. Biber reads the `.bcf` and `mybibliography.bib` and creates a `.bbl` file with the details of the entries requested. In this case, the `.bbl` will include the data for `key1` and `key3` but not for `key2`.

Then you run `latex` (or `pdflatex` or...) again, and, possibly, a second time to resolve the citations and produce the bibliography. LaTeX reads the `.bbl` file and integrates the information about `key1` and `key3` into your document.

And they all live happily after....